# Loop though xml and display values in alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, alerts

I have a **string** that is set up as Xml. This was a data set which i filled and then returned as string getXml().

I would like to grab all values under Sub-categories and have a alert show displaying each sub category.

I tried something like this but could not come right:

```
$.parseXML(xml).find('Table').each(function(index){
            var SubCategorySystem = $(this).find('SubCategorySystem').text();
            var SubCategory = $(this).find('SubCategory').text();
            alert(SubCategory);
        });
```

This is how my string looks.

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <SubCategorySystem>Building</SubCategorySystem>
    <SubCategory>Building</SubCategory>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SubCategorySystem>Electrical</SubCategorySystem>
    <SubCategory>Electrical</SubCategory>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SubCategorySystem>Engineering</SubCategorySystem>
    <SubCategory>Engineering</SubCategory>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SubCategorySystem>Inspection</SubCategorySystem>
    <SubCategory>Inspection</SubCategory>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SubCategorySystem>Landscaping</SubCategorySystem>
    <SubCategory>Landscaping</SubCategory>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SubCategorySystem>Mechanical</SubCategorySystem>
    <SubCategory>Mechanical</SubCategory>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SubCategorySystem>Painting</SubCategorySystem>
    <SubCategory>Painting</SubCategory>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SubCategorySystem>Plumbing</SubCategorySystem>
    <SubCategory>Plumbing</SubCategory>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SubCategorySystem>Safety &amp; Security</SubCategorySystem>
    <SubCategory>Safety &amp; Security</SubCategory>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>"
```

Comment: What's exactly not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to load the xml

```
function loadXMLString(txt) {
        try {
            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = "false";
            xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
            return (xmlDoc);
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                parser = new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
                return (xmlDoc);
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e.message)
            }
        }
        return (null);
    }
```

and then call the function like this:

```
var xmlData = loadXMLString(originalxml);
```

Now you can simply do this:

```
var data =  xmlData.getElementsByTagName('SubCategory');
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    alert(data[i].textContent);
}
```

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvvLg/11/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the wrong part is that `$.parseXML(xml)` creates a `XML Document` but it does not return it as an object, so you won't be able to use `jQuery methods` on it.

Wrap it in an object and it should work

```
$($.parseXML(xml)).find('Table')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reference this two functions first

```
function getExtendedNodeValue(nodeName, xmlNode, i)
{
    var node = "";

    if(typeof(xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(nodeName)[i]) != "undefined" && xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(nodeName)[i].hasChildNodes())
    node = xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(nodeName)[i].firstChild.nodeValue;

    return node; 
}

function getNodeLength(nodeName, xmlNode){
    return xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(nodeName).length;
}
```

And below you can loop through

```
var len = getNodeLength("Table",xml);
var SubCategorySystem = "";
var SubCategory = "";

for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    SubCategorySystem = getExtendedNodeValue("SubCategorySystem",xml,i);
    SubCategory = getExtendedNodeValue("SubCategory",xml,i);

    console.log(SubCategorySystem + " == " + SubCategory);
}
```

You can find this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AjQp7/)